# JQuery Sort, change html code

Tags: jquery

I have this code:

```
<div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="cell">
    <h3 class="value">string4</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    <h3 class="value">string6</h3>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="cell">
      <h3 class="value">string1</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
      <h3>string3</h3>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="cell">
      <h3 class="value">string2</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
      <h3 class="value">string5</h3>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I need a JQuery function that sort and move those "terminal" divs into the correct "container" div.

The output should be:

```
<div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="cell">
    <h3 class="value">string1</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    <h3 class="value">string2</h3>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="cell">
      <h3 class="value">string3</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
      <h3 class="value">string4</h3>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="cell">
      <h3 class="value">string5</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
      <h3 class="value">string6</h3>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I tried a lot of code out here and the closest result i got was with  this:

```
$('.row').sort(function (a, b) {
    return $(a).find('.value').text() > $(b).find('.value').text();
}).each(function (_, container) {
    $(container).parent().append(container);
});
```

But it doesn't order the elements inside each container.
By the way please explain that jquery script, i cannot fully understand what it does.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, i have solved the main problem that is order those cells with this code

    var ordered=$('.cell').sort(function (a, b) {
        return $(a).find('.value').text() >  $(b).find('.value').text()
    })

    var allRows=$('.row');

    var index=0;
    for(var i=0;i<allRows.length;i++){
        $(allRows[i]).append(ordered[index]);
        index++;
        $(allRows[i]).append(ordered[index]);
        index++;
    };

But now i have a new issue, if i have the "values" with caps and non caps, i get a wrong sort
I tried .toLowerCase() in the sort condition but it isnt working

Comment: Got it, i have to change the sort condition:

var ordered=$('.cell').sort(function (a, b) {
                var alc = $(a).find('.value').text().toLowerCase(), blc = $(b).find('.value').text().toLowerCase();
                return alc > blc ? 1 : alc < blc ? -1 : 0;
            });

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
        var ordered=$('.cell').sort(function (a, b) {
            var alc = $(a).find('.value').text().toLowerCase(), blc = $(b).find('.value').text().toLowerCase();
            return alc > blc ? 1 : alc < blc ? -1 : 0;
        });

        var theRows=$('.row');

        var index=0;
        for(var i=0;i<=theRows.length;i++){

           $(theRows[i]).append(ordered[index]);
           index++;

           $(theRows[i]).append(ordered[index]);
           index++;
        };
```